# Need suggestion to make an application to make an feed reader application

Tags: iphone, xcode

Hi i want to make an feed reading application that it should look like this[image]

Here i want to make an application that reads data from different websites. The data should be seperate in category wise and should the number of updates should come in badges with respect to different category.
But i got a problem that there is no availability of creating badges inside a view like the picture in the above, there is only possibility to create on application icon, Please help me in which way i can achieve the target like in the picture. What should i use to create icons like NEWS, ADVISORS etc like in picture and how can we use badges in those icons inside a view.
Thank you if anyone help me in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i would like to share something related to RSS Feeds. These are in XML Format. If you see the XML of feeds you will easily get the category of the feed.

For badges i would like to suggest create icons with empty badges (i.e, without numbers) and add labels fit into the red badge area. update labels from your code with number of updates.

Thanks

Comment: To create that icon which object we should use, there is no object available in the xcode library to create from interface builder, if there is code to create icons please post that code to create icons manually.

Comment: that's right, i suggest create images of those icon and add them on custom button background.

Comment: but for button there is no possibility to add badge. What should i do

Comment: Ok let me explain. create image for your category as i can see in the above image those look like multiple pages along with the red circle on the top right corner without any numbers. Now create custom UIButton and add this image as button background. after this add label that overlap your button so that it appear on the red circle. Create iboutlet for labels and assign text programatically.

Comment: Ok thank you so much i got it now

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Three20](http://three20.info/) library for the view, specifically the [launcher](http://three20.info/showcase/launcher)